# Syncing data between services using Kafka JDBC Connector

Tags: microservices, apache-kafka-connect

I have a system with a microservice architecture. It has two services: **Service A** and **Service B** each with it's own database like in the following diagram.
[image]

As far as I understand having a separate database for each service is a better approach. In this design each service is the owner of its data, it's responsible for creating, updating, deleting and enforcing constraints.

In order to have **Service A** data in **Database B** I was thinking of using JDBC Kafka Connector, but I am not sure if **Table1** and **Table2**  in **Database B** should enforce constraints from **Database A**.

If the constraint, like the foreign key from **Table2** to **Table1** should exist in **Database B** then, is there a way to have the connector know about this?

What are other common or better ways to sync data or solve this problem?

The easiest solution seems to sync per table without any constraints in **Database B**. That would make things easier but it could also lead to a situation where **Service's A** data in **Service B** is inconsistent. For example having entries in **Table2** that point to a non-existing entry in **Table1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the constraint, like the foreign key from Table2 to Table1 should
> exist in Database B then, is there a way to have the connector know
> about this?

No unfortunately the "Kafka JDBC Connector" does not know about constraints.

Based on your question I assume that Table1 and Table2 are duplicated tables in Database B which exist in Database A. In Database A you have constraints which you are not sure you should add in Database B?
If that is the case then I am not sure if using "Kafka JDBC Connector" to sync data is the best choice.

You have a couple options:

1. **Enforce the usage of Constraints** like Foreign Keys in Database B but you would need to update it from your application level and not through "Kafka JDBC Connector". So for this option you can not use "Kafka JDBC Connector". You would need to write some small service/worker to read the data from that Kafka topic and populate your database tables. This way you control what is saved to the db and you can validate the constraints even before trying to save to your database. But the question here is do you really need to have the Constraints? They are important in micro-service-A but do you really need them in micro-service-B as it is just a copy of the data?
2. **Not use constraints and allow temporary inconsistency**. This is common in micro-services world. When working with Distributed systems you always have to think about the CAP Theorem. So you take into account that some data might at some point be inconsistent but you have to make sure that you will eventually bring it back to consistent state. This means you would need to develop on your application level some cleanup/healing mechanism which will recognize this data and correct it. So Db constraints do not necessary have to be enforced on data which the micro-service does not own and is considered as External data to that micro-service Domain.
3. **Rethink your design.** Usually we duplicate data in micro-service-B from micro-service-A in order to avoid coupling between the services so that the service micro-service-B can live and operate even when the micro-service-A is down or not running for some reason. We also do it to reduce load from micro-service-B to micro-service-A for every operation which needs data from Table1 and Table2. Table1 and Table2 are owned by micro-service-A and micro-service-A is the only source of truth for this data. Micro-service-B is using a duplicate of that data for its operations.
   Looking at your databases design following questions might help you figuring out what would be the best option for you system:
   **Is it necessary to duplicate the data in micro-service-B?**
   **If I duplicate the data do I need both tables and do I need all their columns/data in micro-service-B?** Usually you just store/duplicate only a subset of the Entity/Table that you need.
   **Do I need the same table structure in micro-service-A as in micro-service-A?** You have to decide this based on your Domain but very often you Denormalize your tables and change them in order to fit the needs of micro-service-B operations. As usually all these design decisions depend on your application Domain and use case.